# Strapi Server wasn't able to start properly. /documentation/: policy.split is not a function

Tags: mongodb, strapi

I recently encountered this error while starting strapi app. Everything was fine before. I have been searching but still no clue how to solve this. Has anyone encountered this error before?

```
> strapi start

[2021-01-23T11:19:49.618Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2021-01-23T11:19:49.619Z] error Error creating endpoint get /documentation/: policy.split is not a function or its return value is not iterable
```

Please note that my app has no path `/documentation`. Except for strapi default path for its documentation.

Here my app dependencies, I tried with node 10, 12, 14, 15. All have the same error:

```
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "excel4node": "^1.7.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.11",
    "os": "^0.1.1",
    "sha256": "^0.2.0",
    "strapi": "3.0.0-beta.20.3",
    "strapi-admin": "3.0.0-beta.20.3",
    "strapi-connector-mongoose": "3.0.0-beta.20.3",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.0.0-beta.20.3",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.0.0-beta.20.3",
    "strapi-plugin-documentation": "^3.0.0-beta.20.3",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "3.0.0-beta.20.3",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "3.0.0-beta.20.3",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.0.0-beta.20.3",
    "strapi-utils": "3.0.0-beta.20.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.5"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow these steps:

1. Replace `^3.0.0-beta.20.3` with `3.0.0-beta.20.3` from `strapi-plugin-documentation` dependency. (Notice the removal of `^`).
2. Remove `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` file.
3. Reinstall the dependencies.

Now re-run Strapi and the issue must be resolved.

Comment: That so simple. I didnt realize the `^` prefix is causing incompatible error. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

drop your table/schema and then create it again, go back to your terminal and run your start. The error will go away and your server will run as normal. This will be fixed in the next stripe version:
solution: [Strapi server start error](https://forum.strapi.io/t/server-wasnt-able-to-start-properly/9352/2)